# forwarding the ssh port fails when running two vagrant instances from the same host?

Tags: vagrant

Trying to run two vagrant instances on the same host.  The vagrant files on the first instance does nothing special with the SSH ports:

```
# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 9080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 9081
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9990, host: 9090
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8983, host: 8983
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8985, host: 8985
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 2181, host: 2181
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8002, host: 8002
# If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
# Default value: false
# config.ssh.forward_agent = true
```

And this instance spins up as expected:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Resuming suspended VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
```

The second instance forwards port guest 22 to host 2221:

```
# Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
# within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
# accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 10080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80,   host: 45678
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9999, host: 10999
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 10900
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 22, host: 2221
```

But when it spins up, I'm still getting conflicts on port 22222:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening 
on these ports. The forwarded port to 2222 is already in use on the host     
machine.

To fix this, modify your current projects Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding.
```

So I had this working, with the same two vagrant files 3 months ago. It seems like there has been an update to the underlying 'hashicorp/precise32' boxes without a corresponding documentation change, and modifications to the ssh port forrwarding are no longer allowed?  Updating the config.ssh.port would seem to require a change to the underlying image.

Thoughts?

==================================================
Update:
Launching the 2nd instance (forwards 22 => 2221), then reloading produces the following output:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Resuming suspended VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!

Elizabeth@Work /cygdrive/c/Gui-again
$ vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8080 => 10080 (adapter 1)
    default: 80 => 45678 (adapter 1)
    default: 9999 => 10999 (adapter 1)
    default: 9000 => 10900 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2221 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 4.3
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/OSC/PBD-Gui-again
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run
```

So somewhere the ssh port is being forced to 2222. This isn't in the vagrant file itself, where else to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding an 'id ssh' to the end

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2221, id: 'ssh'
```

Or maybe this works for you, to first disable the ssh port (Depends on the Vagrant version)

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2221, id: "ssh", disabled: true
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2221, auto_correct: true
```

Source:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3232

Comment: That did it. I had to bring the VM with forwarded port 22 up and then reload it before the change took, but I can live with that.   Thanks!